# ASIHTTPRequest CFRunLoopRun() crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, ios7, asihttprequest

I've inherited an old project that uses ASIHTTPRequest for networking, which I'm trying to update for iOS 7. I'm performing a request but keep getting a crash that happens here:

[image]

The crash seems to occur on my iPad 2 device consistently, and the 64-bit simulator intermittently. I enabled Zombies based on info from some other SO questions, and got this in the log:

> -[CFNumber release]: message sent to deallocated instance

My project is built with ARC, but I have all of the ASIHTTPRequest classes set to ignore ARC with `-fno-objc-arc`. I know ASIHTTPRequest is old and no longer supported, but I'm unable to perform a full networking refactor at the moment.

It seems that, somewhere in the depths of ASIHTTPRequest, an object is being released twice. Obviously it's not a good idea to modify ASIHTTPRequest's code, but is there a way I can fix this crash?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this crash? I'm seeing the same issue in our code too.

Comment: Same here - can you please let us know if you did find a fix before we have to perform a full networking refactor for our apps.